# How do i print/echo php arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

How would i go about printing my php array in my javascript code? i tried different things but it would only print out the last number.

In the code below where i wrote 'Print the array here', is where i would like to print my php array (if it wasnt already obvious).

PHP example:

```
$phpArray = array('bunch of numbers');
```

Javascript example:

```
let time_chart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type:'line', 
        data:{
            labels:['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4'],
            datasets:[{
                label:'Minutes',
                data:[
                    'Print the array here'
                ],
```

Comment: Don't create Javascript on the fly like that - to send data from the server to the client, use `data-` attributes, `application/json`, or a network request.

Comment: you need to enclose it in PHP tags. <?php echo $phpArray ?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should not be in a separate `.js` file. It should be inside php file. Then only you can use PHP tags in your JS code.

If above is the case then,

```
let time_chart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type:'line', 
        data:{
            labels:['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4'],
            datasets:[{
                label:'Minutes',
                data: <?php echo json_encode($phpArray);?>,
```

Answer (score 0):

if your file is php

```
data:[<?php echo json_encode($phpArray) ?>],
```

OR

```
data:<?php echo json_encode($phpArray) ?>,
```

Comment: Still only prints out the last number of my array :/

Comment: @simplex hows your array look like ?

Comment: just for testing, try `echo var_export($phpArray, true)` instead

Comment: i fetch my array data from a microsoft database (via sqlsrv) (not my database). Im working with a database that is on a server where i work, and it was made by another company might i add

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid mixing PHP and JavaScript - they're separate languages for a reason. Best way I recommend is using hidden inputs with data-tags:

html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="my-array" data-value="<?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>" />
```

jquery:

```
var array = $('#my-array').data('value');

// ...
data: array
// ...
```